# why not we assume $x_n \to x$ weakly as $ n \to \infty?$

Tags: functional-analysis

**Schur's Theorem**: In $\ell^1$ weak convergence of $x_n$ is the same as convergence in the norm.

I found the proof [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Esarason/Class_Webpages/solutions_202B_assign13.pdf)

In the beginning  of the proof it is written that   assume  $x_n \to 0$  weakly as $ n \to \infty$

My confusion : why  not we  assume $x_n \to x$  weakly as $ n \to \infty?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume WLOG that $x=0$ by considering $y_n := x_n - x$.